# How to set a canvas background color to flash for 'n' seconds?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, windows-phone-8, canvas

I know how to set a canvas background color to a solid color but I'm wondering how I would set the background color to flash for 'n' seconds then go back to normal.

The reason I'm asking is because I'm developing a sports timer where the flashing color acts as a visual cue to begin.

As far as I can see there is not standard attribute to achieve this in C# which is why I asked programmatically.

I'm guessing it would involve HTML5 or java script which I don't have any experience in as of yet.

Does anyone have any experience in this area or have advice on a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Microsoft Expression Blend if you are building native app.You can add Story board and try with that.

Answer (score 2):

One way to change the background color of a canvas is using javascript:

This code changes the background of a canvas with id='canvas':

```
document.getElementById("canvas").style.backgroundColor ='green';
```

Example code and a Demo using requestAnimationFrame to change backgrounds at an interval:

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3w2k5r87/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var startTime;
    var interval=1000;
    var index=0;
    var colors=['green','blue','gray','purple'];

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);


    function animate(time){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        if(!startTime){startTime=time;}
        var elapsed=time-startTime;
        if(elapsed>interval){
            startTime=time;
            canvas.style.backgroundColor=colors[index];
            if(++index>colors.length){index=0;}
        }

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a fiddle right here : http://jsfiddle.net/e9hay6u3/

HTML :

```
<div class="smth"> 
<button id="active">Active</button>
    <button id="nactive">Non-Active</button>
  <div id="imADiv">Im a div</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imADiv{
  margin-top:50px;
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
  position:absolute;
}

@-webkit-keyframes demo {
    0% {
        background-color: transparent;
        opacity:1;
    }
    50% {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    100% {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
}

.active{
  -webkit-animation-name: demo;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: demo;
    -moz-animation-duration: 500ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.smth').on('click','#active',function(){
  $('#imADiv').addClass('active');
});

$('.smth').on('click','#nactive',function(){
  $('#imADiv').removeClass('active');
});
```

You need the 'active' transition, i suppose. This is what i understand by flash